# additional space between sidebar and top bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code is a bit messy as i am learning bootstrap.

How do i go about resolving the empty space between the top and side bar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

        <style type="text/css">
.navbar-brand>img {
   max-height: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;


   /* probably not needed anymore, but doesn't hurt */
   -o-object-fit: contain;
   object-fit: contain; 

}
</style>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <!-- <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com"><img src="http://disputebills.com/site/uploads/2015/10/dispute.png" alt="Dispute Bills"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>

    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        TER
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "panel panel-default">
                        <div class = "panel-header">
                            <h1> TER</H1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class = "panel panel-default">
                            <div class = "panel-body">
                                <img src="images.jpg" class="img-circle " alt="Cinque Terre" width="200" height="200">
                            </div>
                                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <h1>TER</h1>

                        <div class = "panel panel-default">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id ="charts-wrapper">
            <div class = "container-fluid">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div col = "col-lg-3">
                        haha
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->


    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>

</body>
```

Attached is a snippet of the page.

[image]

I would like the side and top bar to be joined together as bar of the template frame of my webpage.

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: would you share a plunkeror fiddle for the above coe.Thanks

Comment: I am using too much external resources that i do not know how to use fiddler. Sorry. It seems to render poorly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added any extra CSS to this design, or only working off of the Bootstrap default CSS file?

If the latter, just go into that file and find the classes that reference the navbar and the sidebar, then take note of the position and margin elements.

The navbar is likely going to have a 'fixed' position, which is obvious being that it is stuck to the top of the page no matter the scroll position.

You probably want the sidebar to scroll with the rest of the page though, so you'll want to set the margins for the top of the sidebar div to 0. Then you want to set the position of the sidebar-wrapper div to 'absolute' if it's not already, then add the following:

```
left:0;
```

that should do it, but if not (depending on the div hierarchy), try adding the following as well:

```
top:[px height of navbar];
```

Comment: Sorry i am not sure which are you talking about. I added new CSS. Added it to my question

Comment: The code you have here is setting the sidebar as 'fixed' and the navbar is scrolling - is this what you actually wanted? I've edited it here if you want to take a look:

http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/qbRaZQ

--------------------------------------------------------------------
I fixed the navbar to the top and allowed the sidebar to scroll. Please clarify if this is not your desired result.

Comment: If you'd like to see the exact changes I made, check the following properties of .wrapper, #sidebar-wrapper, and .navbar:

margin-top, padding-top, position, top/left, and z-index. The relations between different position types is extremely important in CSS and you should definitely Google around for some more information (there will be tons of it) - you will find a whole lot of your problems disappear once you understand how they work with each other, and you'll also get some design ideas you hadn't thought possible before.

Comment: Final note: if you are just learning to use CSS, I strongly recommend that you hold off from using Bootstrap and build a site from nothing. You will learn so much more, and much faster. If you need anything else, send me an email - me@joeltbennett.com

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is remove the margin from the bottom of the `.navbar` which is 20px by default.

```
.navbar.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

See working Snippet.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* probably not needed anymore, but doesn't hurt */
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
}
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <!-- <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> -->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com">
        <img src="http://disputebills.com/site/uploads/2015/10/dispute.png" alt="Dispute Bills">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</div>
<div id="wrapper">

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
                        TER
                    </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-header">
            <h1> TER</H1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="images.jpg" class="img-circle " alt="Cinque Terre" width="200" height="200">
            </div>
            <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
          <h1>TER</h1>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="charts-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div col="col-lg-3">
          haha
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```